# The principal submatrix of projection matrix with Gaussian design

Tags: normal-distribution, simulation, multivariate-normal-distribution, projection, norm

I've come across a phenomenon from a simulation that I'm very curious about.
But I don't know how to start my analysis. So, I am **asking for some guidance.**

Thanks!

---

Denote by $\mathbf{H}$ the [principal submatrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)#:%7E:text=A%20principal%20submatrix%20is%20a,of%20column%20indices%20that%20remain.) (of order $K$) of projection matrix $\mathbf{P} = \mathbf{X} (\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{X}^T$. I'm wondering about the consistency of $\ell_2$-norm of $\mathbf{H}$.

Suppose we have $n$ i.i.d observations from multinomial distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}_p, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{p \times p})$, where $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{p \times p}$ is of full rank and $p$ is a constant. Denote by $\mathbf{X}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$ the sample matrix. With high probability, it holds that $\text{rank}(X)=p$. So $(\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X})^{-1}$ and $\mathbf{P}$ exist.

**It seems that $\|\mathbf{H}\|_2 \to 0$. Is it true?**

**How can I theoretically get the (rate of) convergence of $\|H\|_2$?**

---

Numerically, I've tried to simulate some Gaussian random variables and the results are shown in the following figures.

[image: Curves of decline]

**It shows that $\|\mathbf{H}\|_2$ converges to $0$, and the rate is faster than $\sqrt{n}$.**

Note 1: $c$ is a scale constant.
Note 2: $K=n/2$ in this simulation.